# What is the scope of a public key added by apt-key?

Tags: apt, package-management

I was wondering a public key added by `apt-key` is

- per repository (all packages in a repository are authenticated with the same public key) or
- per package (different packages in the same repository may be authenticated with different public keys).

The manpage of `apt-key` says

> apt-key is used to manage the list of keys used by apt to authenticate **packages**. Packages
>   which have been authenticated using these keys will be considered trusted.
>
> ...
>   It is critical that keys added manually via apt-key are verified to belong to the owner of
>   **the repositories** they claim to be for.

For example, I was wondering why there is no repository or something else specified as a scope to which a public key is applicable to?

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the packages. I might have a repository with 2 package and sign each package with a different key.

For example a repository might have couple of maintainer and each of them sign packages with their own keys (or sub-keys) so you might have to add different public keys to verify packages from same repository.

However most of the times you only add one public key cause the packages are all signed with one key or related sub-keys thus they can be verified with that single public key.

Comment: We can many public keys with apt-key. In the example, when adding a public key, why is its scope not specified? How does apt know which added key is used for authenticate which package from which repository?

Comment: That's another question. the PGP signature contains the public key's ID. `cat /var/lib/apt/lists/*_InRelease | grep 'BEGIN PGP SIGNA' -A 20 | tail -20`

Comment: That is the question in my post.